# Issues with Term Reference and Multilingual Taxonomy

Tags: taxonomy-terms, i18n-l10n

The issue:

- We have a multilingual Drupal 7 website which allows users access to a content type e.g. `Blog` - where they can use `/node/add/blog` and `node/*/edit` in their chosen language
- A taxonomy has been created called `category` which has been set to 'Localize' under MULTILINGUAL OPTIONS >> Translation mode
- Terms listed under `category` have been translated to FR, DE, NL etc.
- On the content_type `Blog` - a term reference has been set up to reference the `category` taxonomy, with a select list widget being used.
- When visiting e.g. `www.multilingual-site.com/node/add/blog` (default site language is EN) - the dropdown list shows all the terms.
- When visiting e.g. `www.multilingual-site.com/fr/node/add/blog` or any other language e.g. /de/ or /nl/ etc the dropdown list is blank - the translated terms do not appear.

In an attempt to create the option list ourselves - using `hook_form_alter()` with `taxonomy_get_tree($vid)` as suggested here https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/64666/5253 - when trying to dpm the output
the array is empty for every language other than the default EN.

Can anyone offer any direction? Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Turns out we needed to unselect 'Select taxonomy terms by language' - found `admin/config/regional/i18n/select` - hope this helps someone. More reading at: https://drupal.org/node/1868418 #2